# Node.js / Koa get reseponse from web API, and assign to ctx.body

Tags: node.js, api, koa

I got this in my Koa app, and I can get response from this Movie-Database API, I want to show the result in front end page, but I got 404 Not found, which means ctx.body did not get the result.

```
router
    .get('/', async (ctx) => {
        await ctx.render('index', { // render index.html

        })
    })
    .post('/searchMovie', async (ctx) => {
        let name = ctx.request.body
        console.log(name)

        var req = await unirest("GET", "https://movie-database-imdb-alternative.p.rapidapi.com/")
            .query({
                "page": "1",
                "r": "json",
                "s": `${name}`
            })
            .headers({
                "x-rapidapi-host": "movie-database-imdb-alternative.p.rapidapi.com",
                "x-rapidapi-key": key,
                "useQueryString": true
            })
            .end((res) => {
                if (res.error) throw new Error(res.error);
                console.log(res.body)
                ctx.body = res.body
            })
    });
```

This is html page, use fetch send the movie's name I want to search to back-end.
And send request to API.

```
<body>
    <form>
        <input type="text" id="MovieName">
        <input type="button" onclick="search()" value="post">
    </form>
    <script>
        async function search() {
            let movieName = document.getElementById('MovieName').value

            let r = await fetch("/searchMovie", {
                method: 'POST',
                body: `${movieName}`
            }).then((response) => {
                console.log(response)
                return response.json
            }).then((data) => {
                console.log(data)
                return data
            }).catch((error) => {
                throw error
            })
        }

    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Does the `unirest().query().headers().end()` function return a promise? It looks very callback based, so it's possible that `await` doesn't do anything. If this is the case I would recommend a promise or async/await based HTTP library instead of unireset.

Comment: It can work without `await`, and I check Unirest's npm documentation, it is a set of lightweight HTTP libraries, by the way, I use it base on rapid API documentation, and my problem is still stack.

Comment: The problem is that your `end()` handler is likely fired *after* the `search` function is done, so too late...

Comment: Try setting a few `console.log()` statements so you can see what the order is

Comment: If `end()` does not return a promise, the `await` doesn't do anything.